# How can I access a variable from an actionListener insider another actionListener?

Tags: java, scope, jbutton, actionlistener, jcombobox

```
private int var = 0;

test(){
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String selection = (String) items.getSelectedItem();

            for (int i = 0; i < itms.length; i++) {
                if (selection == itms[i]) {
                    var = 10 + i;

                    System.out.println(var); // prints the desired value
                }
            }
        }
    };

    System.out.println(var); // prints 0 but why not desired value???
}
```

This actionListener is for a combo box. I want to take the value of the selected item in the combo box and give that to another actionListener which will append a new value to the var from the original actionListener based on which JButton is selected. How can I get the value of var from inside this actionListener and use it in another actionListener that is also in the same constructor? Is that even possible? Is there a better approach?

Comment: From what I see, the 2nd print statement is getting called immediately after creating the listener. As for the code in the listener, that doesn't execute until an event actually happens. Does `0` print first?

Comment: What do you mean by appending another value to a var, when your var is an `int`?  An `int` holds only one value.  You can't append another value to it.

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes 0 prints first until i make a selection in the combobox.

Comment: @ajb I will convert them to Strings and then append them them to make a longer "integer" value.

Answer (score 1):

Your `actionPerformed()` method will get executed as when its event occurs, but this is not the case with print statement outside the `actionPerformed()`.

So this statement

```
System.out.println(var); // prints 0 but why not desired value???
```

gets executed whenever you create an object of your `test` class (It is preferred to name it **`Test`** class according to Java naming conventions) because the print statement is written inside the constructor. In contrast, your print statement inside the `actionPerformed` method will get executed and print the correct value which you is your "desired value", whenever the event occurs.